# Why am I getting 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I'm making a guilded bot and this error appears each time I'm running it. Here's what Node.JS prints out:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:452
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Apps\Codings\PROJECTS\GUILDED BOT\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:444:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:715:18)
    at resolveMainPath (node:internal/modules/run_main:26:23)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:24)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\Apps\\Codings\\PROJECTS\\GUILDED BOT\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\Apps\\Codings\\PROJECTS\\GUILDED BOT'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

I tried the steps from this link to fix it but to no avail: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-cannot-find-module-node-npm-error-solved/

Comment: Does `C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Apps\Codings\PROJECTS\GUILDED BOT\index.js` exist?

Comment: I think Node.JS got confused. index.js is in src folder. How do I make Node to run the script in the src folder?

Comment: Ok I changed the index.js location to what Node.JS is asking and now I'm having this error: 'TypeError: Client is not a constructor'

Comment: You had your `main` field in `package.json` set to `index.js` but you want `src/index.js` instead